# Can we get a "git blame" for documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Can documentation get something similar to `git blame`? That is, something so I can figure out who contributed a given line?

It's always nice to know who did what.

Comment: As a much belated side-note, why wouldn't documentation be maintained in an SCM system, just like code?  On one of my projects, a [complete "book" style manual](https://mongo.webcore.io) is being [prepared in an orphan branch](https://github.com/marrow/mongo/tree/book) of an existing repository, to keep it separate, but not _too_ separate.